# Chaining array PBS jobs

Tags: arrays, bash, hpc, qsub, pbs

I am trying to chain two calculation jobs using the PBS high performance computer job scheduler. My scripts are as follows:

Script called **1.pbs**:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #PBS -N 1
 #PBS -q thin
 #PBS -l walltime=0:03:00
 #PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1
 #PBS -j oe
 #PBS -J 1-10

 cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
 echo 'SCRIPT 1'
 qsub -W depend=afterok:${PBS_ARRAY_ID} 2.pbs
```

Script called **2.pbs**:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #PBS -N 2
 #PBS -q thin
 #PBS -l walltime=0:03:00
 #PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1
 #PBS -j oe

 cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
 echo 'SCRIPT 2'
```

Since script **1.pbs** is an array (run 10 copies of the script), when the array finishes script **2.pbs** will also run 10 copies (1 from each submitted 1.pbs during the array job).

My question is: How can I setup these two scripts as to have script **1.pbs** run normally as an array, then after all the array jobs finish script **2.pbs** is run *ONLY ONCE*.

Answer (score 0):

One approach: have 1.pbs touch a semaphore file in /tmp/ as a condition for doing the `qsub`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run "qsub -W depend" from inside of the 1st job.

Run it like this:

my1job=`qsub 1.pbs`
qsub -W depend=afterok:$my1job 2.pbs